# Can't open any project on Android Studio 0.3.4

Tags: android-studio

I just finished updating Android Studio to ver0.3.4 and now I'm not able to open any project, 
it shows me the following error:

[image: Android studio error]

What can I do to solve this issue? Anybody has the same?

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution by myself, it seems to be a GNU/Linux specific problem, to resolve that, launch this command from terminal

```
rm android-studio/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-*-1.8.jar
```

further details on [google code thread](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=62019)